# Application.Run stops the current code

Tags: vba, excel

I am opening 2 separate instances of excel and Application.run is working to run a macro in my other workbook but it stops all the code below it even when I close out that application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that inside of your macro you have an "end" which is being stopped at which stops all code from running even the parent who is executing the child. Replace the "end" with an "exit".

Comment: Did you just refer to yourself as "You"?

Comment: @PJRosenburg One might ask how one would speak to oneself in the second person.

Comment: I wondered that myself.  One would ask a question and reply as if it were another inquiring.